# Trigger an animation on one element by hovering over another element

Tags: html, css

I am new to this and I'm stuck on a project.
I am trying to get an animation to cause an image to appear on the page when you hover over another element.

I already have the animation working, but what I can't figure out is how first to make the image invisible and the cause the animation to start when the said element is hovered in this case a h4 element.

I've tried everything I can think of and read several other posts relating to this but no luck. I think it might be something with me having to add position (absolute or relative) but I'm not sure.

This is the css for that section without any hovering function:

```css
.timeline-img {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.hovered:hover + p + .timeline-img {
    animation: 7s alternate slideIn;
    transition: all .2s;
    visibility: visible;
}  

.hovered:hover:after + p + .timeline-img {
    visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      margin-left: 100%;
      width: 300%; 
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      margin-left: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <h4 class="hovered">Shepherds discovered coffee in Ethiopia circa 800 A.D.</h4>
   <p>Legend has it that 9th century goat herders noticed the effect caffeine had on their goats, who appeared to "dance" after eating coffee berries. A local monk then made a drink with coffee berries and found that it kept him awake at night, thus the original cup of coffee was born.</p>
  <div class="timeline-img">
    <img src="shepherd.jpg" alt="Shepherd" class="fact-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to whoever helps me out and please explain as I'm still very new to this and learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

The syntax is straightforward enough: just two or more selectors separated by a plus (+) symbol. The simplest construction is two elements with a plus between them. read more: [Adjacent-Sibling Selector](https://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html)

```css
.content h4:hover + p + .timeline-img{
    animation: 7s alternate slideIn;
    transition: all .2s;
}
@keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      margin-left: 100%;
      width: 300%; 
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      margin-left: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <h4 class="hovered">Shepherds discovered coffee in Ethiopia circa 800 A.D.</h4>
   <p>Legend has it that 9th century goat herders noticed the effect caffeine had on their goats, who appeared to "dance" after eating coffee berries. A local monk then made a drink with coffee berries and found that it kept him awake at night, thus the original cup of coffee was born.</p>
 <div class="timeline-img">
    <img src="shepherd.jpg" alt="Shepherd" class="fact-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. However, I ran into an issue. What I want is for the image to be previously invisible by setting the display or visibility properties and when you hover over the H4, the animation should commence with the image sliding in. However, that happens but the image disappears if I stop hovering. I have tried adding a :after pseudo class to the :hover like so: .hovered:hover:after + p + .timeline-img {visibility: visible;} but this didn't work either. I have edited my earlier CSS above to include the invisible images and the the new selector. Thanks & help if you can.

Comment: do you mean image should be hidden initially and when you hover h4 and on hover out image should be visible always? i guess you need jquery or javascript forthat

Answer (score 0):

In this example,

1. We set a `:hover` pseudo-class on the target sibling (`~`) class.

   - i.e. `.hovered:hover ~ .timeline-img`
2. We then use the `animation-play-state` property on the standard + hover state items.

   - `animation-play-state: paused`
   - `animation-play-state: running`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

```css
.timeline-img {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
  /* necessary */
  -webkit-animation: 2s alternate slideIn;
          animation: 2s alternate slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
          animation-play-state: paused;
  /* Optional */
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
          animation-iteration-count: 2;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.hovered:hover ~ .timeline-img {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
          animation-play-state: running;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.red {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h4 class="hovered">Shepherds discovered coffee in Ethiopia circa 800 A.D.
  </h4>
  <p>
    Legend has it that 9th century goat herders noticed the effect caffeine had on their goats, who appeared to "dance" after eating coffee berries. A local monk then made a drink with coffee berries and found that it kept him awake at night.
  </p>
  <div class="timeline-img">
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```css
.timeline-img{
    transition: all .2s;
    animation: 7s alternate slideIn;
    animation-play-state: paused;  
} 

.hovered:hover ~ .timeline-img{
  animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      margin-left: 100%;
      width: 300%; 
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      margin-left: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
   <h4 class="hovered">Shepherds discovered coffee in Ethiopia circa 800 A.D.</h4>
   <p>Legend has it that 9th century goat herders noticed the effect caffeine had on their goats, who appeared to "dance" after eating coffee berries. A local monk then made a drink with coffee berries and found that it kept him awake at night, thus the original cup of coffee was born.</p>
  <div class='timeline-img'>
    <img src="shepherd.jpg" alt="Shepherd" class="fact-img">
  </div>
</div>
```